# Why doesn't Rambam codify the obligation/recommendation to honor one's father-in-law?

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, rambam, mechilta, honoring-in-laws

Mechilta dR Yishmael and more explicitly Mechilta dRashbi both make the point that from Moshe's honoring his father in law Yisro (Shemos 18:7) one sees that one ought to honor ones father in law as one honors ones father.

Mechilta dR Yishmael (Shemos 18:17):

> מִכָּן אָמְרוּ, שֶׁיְּהֵא הָאָדָם מוּכָן לִכְבוֹד חָמִיו

Mechilta dRashbi Shemos (18:7):

> וישתחו וישק לו וישאלו איש לרעהו לשלום – אין אנו יודעין מי נשתחוה למי
> ומי נשק למי: מי שמענו שקרוי איש לא משה כענין שנ' (במדבר י"ב:י"ג) והאיש
> משה עניו מאד הא לא נשתחוה ולא נישק אלא משה ליתרו מיכאן אמרו לעולם יהא
> אדם נוהג כבוד בחמיו וכן דויד אמר לשאול ואבי ראה גם ראה (שמואל ב
> כ"ד:י"ב) מלמד שהיה נוהג בו כבוד ככבוד אביו. –

Both the Tur and SA codify it as obligatory

Tur YD 240:24:

> וחייב לכבד חמיו דכתיב אבי ראה גם ראה

SA YD 240:24:

> חייב אדם לכבד חמיו

Torah Temimah (to the above mentioned pasuk) brings the former source and wonders why poskim don't cite it with Rambam leaving out the halacha entirely

> (והנה מה שיליף מדרשה זו שחייב אדם בכבוד חמיו צ״ע שלא ילפו הפוסקים מכאן והביאו ממדרש שוח״ט ממה שקרא דוד לשאול שהיה חותנו בשם אבי כמ״ש ואבי ראה גם ראה (שמואל א כ״ד) עיין בטור יו״ד ס״ס ר״מ, וברמב״ם פ״ו מממרים לא הובא כלל דין זה, וזה תימה שלשון המכילתא מכאן אמרו משמע דהוא הלכה ברורה וידועה, והב״ח בטור שם כתב טעם שהשמיטו הפוסקים דין זה משום דבמדרש שוח״ט איתא דעת רבנן דהלשון שאמר דוד ואבי ראה לא קרא לשאול אלא לאבנר, וא״כ אזיל ליה כל עיקר דין זה, אבל מה יעשה עם דרשה שלפנינו שמקורה בתורה ונשנית סתמא באין מחלוקת, וצע״ג. וכן מש״כ הב״ח בדעת הטור דאפילו אם מחויב אינו מחויב אלא בערך שאר זקנים ולא בערך כבוד אב, וראייתו ממ״ש דוד ואבי ראה גם ראה, והלשון גם ראה משמע שסמכו במקצת לכבוד אב, והנה לבד שזה המקור קלוש מאד, דמה שייך לשון זה להלשין אבי דמיניה עיקר הילפותא, אלא דלענין דינא אין זה נכון, שהרי כאן כתיב במשה וישתחו וישק לו ומכאן למדו לכבוד חותנו, ובודאי אין מחויבים בהשתחואה ונשיקה לסתם זקנים.)

Does anyone know why the Rambam doesn't codify the obligation/recommendation to honor one's father-in-law?

Comment: I believe the sefer חרדים says that the mitzva is the mitva of כיבוד אב because אשתו כגופו. If so the rambam does list that.

Comment: @אילפא Where is that source pls?

Comment: https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=66231&st=&pgnum=56

Comment: @אילפא Very interesting. I don't think that suffices and Rambam should have written it regardless but I do appreciate the source. Tyvm. If u write it as an answer I'll give u an upvote.

Comment: "Mechilta dR Yishmael and more explicitly Mechilta dRashbi both make the point " Can you please cite the exact lashon used or where it can be found?

Comment: @Deuteronomy מכילתא דרבי ישמעאל שמות שמות י"ח:ז'
מִכָּן אָמְרוּ, שֶׁיְּהֵא הָאָדָם מוּכָן לִכְבוֹד חָמִיו.

Comment: @Deuteronomy מכילתא דרשב"י שמות שמות י"ח:ז'
וישתחו וישק לו וישאלו איש לרעהו לשלום – אין אנו יודעין מי נשתחוה למי ומי נשק למי: מי שמענו שקרוי איש לא משה כענין שנ' (במדבר י"ב:י"ג) והאיש משה עניו מאד הא לא נשתחוה ולא נישק אלא משה ליתרו מיכאן אמרו לעולם יהא אדם נוהג כבוד בחמיו וכן דויד אמר לשאול ואבי ראה גם ראה (שמואל ב כ"ד:י"ב) מלמד שהיה נוהג בו כבוד ככבוד אביו.

Comment: That was quick, thanks! יְּהֵא הָאָדָם מוּכָן לִכְבוֹד חָמִיו and יהא אדם נוהג כבוד בחמיו don't exactly have the ring of a formal חיוב...

Comment: @Deuteronomy Fair enough. Definitely lessens the bite of the TT's q. Strange that Tur/SA take it to the other extreme with "חייב" (YD 240:24).

Comment: @Deuteronomy If you put that up as an answer together with that Rambam didn't necessarily codify every recommendation found in Chazal or whatever nusach you'd like to use id hit the ✔️

Comment: @Deuteronomy Perhaps the midrash shocher tov uses obligatory language (if you track it down lemme know). I suppose Rambam didn't necessarily consider it authoritative or didn't have it

Comment: @Deuteronomy From Lekach Tov note 27 מיכן שחייב אדם להיות נוהג בחמיו כבוד. במכילתא הגי׳ מכאן אמרו שיהיה האדם מוכן לכבוד חמיו ובילקוט הגי׳ מכאן אמרו שיהא האדם נוהג בכבוד חמיו ועיין במאיר עין אות מ״ח והביא בשם ילקוט שמואל רמז קל״ג שמביא בשם שוחר טוב ואבי ראה גם ראה מכאן שחייב אדם בכבוד חמיו ככבוד אביו וע״ש

Comment: @Deuteronomy I guess that explains it. Rambam didn't reckon with those midrashim as opposed to Tur/SA that did. This is where my research ends lol

Comment: @Nahum if you write it up yourself you can earn the ["self-learner" badge](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/badges/13/self-learner), I'll toss ya an upvote as well ;)

Comment: @Deuteronomy Appreciate that. I'm gonna pass on it for the time being. Ty for cleaning up the Q

Comment: Shu"T Yehawe Da'ath vol. 6, no. 51

ובספר תורה תמימה (פרשת יתרו, יח, ז) כתב על דברי הבית חדש, שאין זה נכון, שהרי במשה נאמר וישתחו וישק לו, ולמדו מזה במכילתא שיהא מוכן אדם לכבוד חמיו, ובשאר זקנים אין חיוב בהשתחואה ונשיקה. וגם מה שכתב בטעם הפוסקים שהשמיטוהו, הרי במכילתא נשנה דין זה בלא חולק. ע"ש. ותימה עליו, שהרי במכילתא לא נאמר בזה לשון חיוב כלל, אלא שיהא אדם מוכן לכבור חמיו. וגם ההשתחואה והנשיקה אינה מצד חיוב, אלא מנהג דרך ארץ. ולכן העיקר כדברי הבית חדש. וע' בברכי יוסף יו"ד (םי' רמ ס"ק כ), ובספר בית אהרן קריספין (דף מו ע"א(. ובשדי חמד )מערכת כ כלל קכ).'

See inside for fuller treatment

Comment: @Deuteronomy Thank you! ברוך שכיוונת!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151227/discussion-between-nahum-and-deuteronomy).

Answer (score 1):

Some suggest (Including Rav Shalom) because the Rambam poskins like Rav yehushua that Moshe gave his wife a get. That mechilta holds Moshe just sent her away like Rav Elazar hamodai. Therfore according to the Rambam Yisro wasnt Moshes father in law.

Comment: Who is Rav Shalom? It is a cute peshat but imo not likely to be true. Additionally, Mechilta cites that machlokes btwn R"Y & R"E and then brings the father in law halacha without anyone arguing on it. Also, the Torah explicitly calls Yisro his shver so if anything acc to R"Y a bigger chumra should come out with one obligated in his shvers kavod even after not being married to his daughter anymore . . I'm giving u an upvote regardless, ty for that answer

Comment: Rav Shalom Shechter in eretz yisrael. Also otzar migadim says that pshat. They hold its pashut they had to be married for mechilta to have a proof.

Comment: Does he have a sefer out or is this oral? Who wrote otzar migadim

Comment: He has a sefer, but i dont have it. A d its not easy to get, he seels it through private seller. Otzar migadim is random yengerliet i think